# Adding properties to object at runtime, and saving to a database

Tags: php, django, oop, model-view-controller, orm

I have a set of model class definitions, each with some properties and methods.

Each new model class definition is mapped to its own database table, the properties forming the table columns. Each newly created object can then be adequately saved for a rainy day.

My question is, how can I elegantly allow for additional properties to be added at runtime, and have it saved without re-migrating all the tables in the database.

For example, say I have an "Article" object with name, creation date and article body as properties (initially), but at runtime a user decides that for a particular article they'd like to add a synopsis as a property, how do I save the new entity to the database?

I guess I'm trying to (amongst other things) mimic adding fields in Drupal or Custom Fields in Wordpress.

As one has to specify the data type of each column when creating or updating a table, the only way I can think of doing this is by creating a column with an array as its data type. This solution feels a bit awkward though, and just wondering how others have done it.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why did you tag this with both PHP and Django? What is it implemented in so far?

Comment: So far php, however I'm having some difficulty with its Reflection API so considering switching to Python and Django

Answer (score 0):

as a lowest common denominator you could persist your objects as a series of key-value pairs, but this sounds clunky and slow. I could also envisage nightmares when you have objects containing objects etc.

Or, you could serialize them before storage (as xml documents, perhaps?) But this forgoes any kind of structure at the database level and would complicate matters if you wished to query the database on specific column values.

But if I were you I'd read up on some "hibernation" utilities e.g. Hibernate (!) to get a feel for how they persist things. These utilities are already solving your exact problem, and you can guarantee they'll have put a fair amount of thought into it.

If you're lucky there may even be such a utility you could use out of the box, without necessarity understanding the nitty gritty.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my nose in the right direction. Although I am digging into Hibernation as you suggest, do you have any good sources you can share with me? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not particularly expert in this area, but I know that Hibernate is an open source project: [http://www.hibernate.org/](http://www.hibernate.org/). A quick glance here shows plenty of documentation, plus source code even if you need to go to that level